# Substracting dates in couchbase?

Tags: database, couchbase, sql++

I have a couchbase bucket that stores two utc dates in the following format:

10-16-2018T18:05:45.823+0000Z

So the document looks like this:

```
{
"date1:"10-16-2018T18:05:45.823+0000",
"date2: "10-17-2018T18:05:45.827+0000"
}
```

I want to create a query that allows me to get the time difference between the two dates in each document. I've tried doing something like this:

```
select date_diff_str('10-16-2018T18:05:45.823+0000','22-11-2018T19:50:45.823+0000','day') as difference;
```

but it doesn't work.  Grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSON there is no timestamp data type.  timestamp is stored as ISO-8601 format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD which can be string comparable. All N1QL date functions works on ISO-8601 format

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/datefun.html

```
 SELECT DATE_DIFF_STR(
                      SUBSTR(date2,6,4)||"-"|| SUBSTR(date2,0,5)||SUBSTR(date2,10),
                      SUBSTR(date1,6,4)||"-"|| SUBSTR(date1,0,5)||SUBSTR(date1,10),"day")
    LET date1 = "10-16-2018T18:05:45.823+00:00", date2="11-17-2018T18:05:45.827+00:00";
```